# arrayadapter clear() not working by pressing back button

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a activity with has a ListView which get´s his data from an ArrayAdapter.
after pressing my backbutton I need a clear ArrayAdapter.I already read a lot of stackoverflow questions, but nothing helped me yet. On my BackbuttonListener I tried

```
        this.adapter.clear();
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But this doesn´t worked.Thanks for help in advanced! :)

```
    String[] things;
ArrayList<String> shoppingList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView lV;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    this.shoppingList = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("shoppingList");
    this.things = shoppingList.toArray(new String[shoppingList.size()]);
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(things));
    //Build Adapter


    this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,                                        // Context
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,         // welches Layout wir benutzen
    items);                                  //Items welche wir darstellen wollen

    //Configure the ListView
    this.lV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    lV.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        Log.w("MyAPP", String.valueOf(this.adapter.getCount()));
            this.adapter.clear();
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: but what's the purpose of clearing the Adapter if your are going to finish the activity?

Comment: Clear your **items** List<String>

Comment: because I want a clear adapter when I am opening the activity again.@PiyushGupta ,I will try it !  Thank you!

Comment: if you fill the adapter in the `onCreate`, when you call the activity it will be always empty

Comment: @PiyushGupta : It doesnt worked :

Comment: this.items.clear();
      this.adapter.clear();
  this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: still not cleaning my ArrayAdapter ...after opening the activity second time I got a listview with twice of data ....

Comment: does someone has a idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
        {
            Log.w("MyAPP", String.valueOf(this.adapter.getCount()));
                items.clear(); 
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: thanks yjomin , but its still giving me, after opening the activity the second time an array twice as big :(

Comment: as in your oncreate this.shoppingList = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("shoppingList"); you are getting the values then it will always remains you should clear this also

Comment: In my back button Listener => this.items.clear();  =>this.shoppingList.clear();=>this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); But it´s still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I am just a newbie in android... I solved this by creating new adapter every time I need to refresh all items in the list. I also need to set all listeners every time but it works. Is there any better solution to dinamicaly show items from some collection?

```
list_view.getAdapter().clear()    
ItemListAdapter adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_row_layout);
list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```